# Downloading many files at once in SSH from Google Cloud?

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform, download, google-compute-engine

I just started working with google cloud on a project (using VM instances). I connected to SSH straight from the browser.

I will have thousands of .txt files in a few directories, and the "Download file" option only allows me to download 1 file at a time.

What's the easiest way to download all those files (or the whole directory) straight to my computer? Or, what method should I use/learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be to install the Cloud SDK on your local machine (see installation instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install)) and use the `gcloud compute scp` command to download your files or directories. For example:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse vm-instance:~/remote-directory ~/local-directory
```

This will copy a remote directory, `~/remote-directory`, from `vm-instance` to the `~/local-directory` directory of your local host. You'll find more details about this command usage [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp).

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward answer; I shall proceed!

Comment: Right now I'm getting an error message "Multiple remote sources not supported by PuTTY". Not sure what's going on, I'm trying to download the files into my downloads folder on my PC.